# How to throw exception for a local object method call?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

MyCode:

```
class LocalClass{
  public getNumber(){
    retunr 5;
  }
}

class AnotherLocalClass{
  public static getNumber(){
    retunr 10;
  }
}

public class A{

  public int methodAa(Boolean flag, int paramValue){
   return methodA(flag, paramValue);
  }

  private int methodA(Boolean flag, int paramValue){
  int returnValue = 0;
    try{
      if(flag){
        LocalClass localVariable = new LocalClass();
        returnValue = localVariable.getNumber() + paramValue;
      } else{
        returnValue = AnotherLocalClass.getNumber() + paramValue;
      }
     return returnValue;
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       return 0;
    }
  }
}

public class ATest{
  @InjectMocks
  A a;
  
  public void methodATest(){
   //need help to write here
  }
}
```

`LocalClass` and `AnotherLocalClass` are classes that contains a method that returns a value.

`getNumber` in `AnotherLocalClass` is a static method.

Class `A` is the main class for which I am writing `ATest` class.

I can only write code in `methodATest`. And cannot change anything in `LocalClass`, `AnotherLocalClass` or class `A`.

I want to write `methodATest` such that `methodA` throws an exception.

My mockito version is 1.19.10 and it cannot be changed.

And also I cannot use PowerMockito or any other new dependency.

Answer (score 0):

What exceptions do you expected to occur on your code? Which parameter values will cause the exceptions? In those cases, what is the return value that you're expecting?

When you get the answers for those questions, then you gonna have to set the conditions for the exception to happen. Then your code is gonna look something like this:

```
public class ATest{
 
  A a = new A();
  
  @Test
  public void methodATest(){
      Boolean flag = ?;
      int paramValue = ?;
      int expectedReturnValue = ?;

      int returnValue = a.methodAa(flag, paramValue);

      assertEquals(expectedReturnValue, returnValue);
  }
}
```

Look out for the mock method. We usually use it when we need to set a class that we don't exactly want it to run it's methods, so we mock then to return something that we need for our test to work.

You can learn more about tests with this tutorial: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html#junittesting

----[Edit]----

If you wanted to mock the LocalClass, you were gonna need to do something like this:

```
@PrepareForTest({LocalClass.class, A.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ATest{
 
   A a = new A();
  
   @Test
   public void methodATest(){
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalClass.class);        
       PowerMockito.when(LocalClass.getNumber()).thenThrow(new Exception());

       ...
   }
}
```

But, the getNumber() method should be static for it to work.
And, since you can not use PowerMockito, it's not possible to mock the class.

----[Edit]----

```
@PrepareForTest({AnotherLocalClass.class, A.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ATest{
 
   A a = new A();
  
   @Test
   public void methodATest(){
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(AnotherLocalClass.class);        
       PowerMockito.when(AnotherLocalClass.getNumber()).thenThrow(new Exception());

       a.methodAa(...);

       ...
   }
}
```

But again, since static method belongs to the class, there is no way in Mockito to mock static methods.

Comment: thank you but `flag` and `paramValue ` can be some value and also `methodA ` is private. I want to write `methodATest` such that in `methodA` an exception occurs and `return 0` inside `catch` is executed.
Something like:
`Mockito.when(/*method call to be mocked*/).thenThrows(Exception.class);`

i tried like:
`Mockito.when(localVariable.getNumber()).thenThrows(Exception.class);`
But I am not able to mock the method call `localVariable.getNumber()`.
So this is the issue I am facing

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is mock the LocalClass. To do so, you're gonna have to mock it staticaly. But since you can't use PowerMockito, i don't think it's possible.

Comment: okay thankyou. but if the `getNumber()` is static in `AnotherLocalClass` class then could we achieve something. Like this is not my original code. The else part also contains a static method call. Let me update the question too.